# Understanding adapter sessions and cookie management

Tags: session, cookies, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm developing an IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1.0 app that consumes several web services that are being protected by gicar/siteminder.

Following recommendations in some tutorials, I have created one adapter called GicarManagementAdapter and a few others adapters, one per web service being consumed.

GicarManagementAdapter contains logic to perform login agains gicar/siteminder. It implements 3 methods:

1. "submitAuthentication": this is the method called by the client at login time. the client uses the recommended ChallengeHandler authorization protocol
2. "onLogout": this is the logout method invoked by the ChallengeHandler at logout time
3. "invokeService": this method is used by others adapters when invoking the backend webservices.

At submitAuthentication method I'm requesting a resource protected by gicar (the wsdl file of one of the web services) through httpClient library. The http requests supplies the authorization header with the credentials supplied by the client. If httr requests succeds the response contains a cookie, GICSESSION, that is stored in the current client session:

```
WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().setAttribute("GICAR-COOKIE", cookieValue);
```

Whenever client application want to access to backend it invokes one of the adapters methods. These methods just build the SOAP body and create the invocationData passed to `GicarManagementAdapter.invokeService` method. invokeService method just takes the invocation data and adds the cookie header stored in the current client session:

```
function invokeService(invocationData) {
var gicarCookie = WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().getAttribute("GICAR-COOKIE");
WL.Logger.info("Invoking service with coookie: " + gicarCookie);
var headers = invocationData.headers || {};
headers['cookie'] = gicarMgmt.cookieName + "=" + gicarCookie;

invocationData.headers = headers;
WL.Server.invokeHttp(invocationData);}
```

(Code is a bit more complex in order to handle response with Session Expired cookie)

Unfortunately I have no control on backend.

I have seen a couple of issues:

1. One of the target platforms of the client app is desktop browser. If I open 3 tabs in Google Chrome that point to desktop app version I can see how GicarManagementAdapter logs 3 times through the httpclient and gets 3 different cookies. However, each time one app queries data to backend the last cookie is used. I mean, no matter what of the each chrome tab (session?) performs the query, WL.Server.getClientRequest().getSession().getAttribute("GICAR-COOKIE"); gets always the same cookie. Does it mean they are all sharing same session?
2. It seems WL.Server.invokeHttp is ignoring tha cookie header supplied. After a while of inactivity (3 minutes) cookie expires. At first invocation after cookie expiration I can see the responds contains a Set-Cookie header with value GICSESSION=LOGGEDOFF. Next invocations result in a redirection form with no any cookie info.

Maybe I'm wrong but it seems that WL.Server.invokeHttp is ignoring the cookie header and is using a cached cookie. If I close all tabs, open again and login again, I get the same result: a redirection form with no cookie header. I only log in again if I redeploy some adapter or restart worklight server.

EDITED on 10/04/2016

I could inspect traffic amongst MFP server and backend. The GicarmanagementAdapter is configured to ignore cookies (I added `<cookiePolicy>IGNORE_COOKIES</cookiePolicy>` tag in the connectivity section of the adapter's xml settings file). I can see that the cookie is being sent correctly to the backend. Problem begins when the cookies expires and the backend sends Set-Cookie: GICSESSION=LOGGEDOFF header. Once MFP server receives this header from an WL.Server.InvokeHttp request it adds this cookie into the next requests. So the flow is as follows:

1. After login, Adapter invokes backend sending the cookie gained at login step
2. After session expiration, Adapter receives a Set-Cookie:GICSESSION=LOGGEDOFF when invokine WL.Server.InvokeHttp
3. Adapter catches LOGGGEDOFF cookie and notifies client that new authentication is required
4. Client invokes submitAuhtentication method again that via apache httpClient gets a new cookie and stores it in the client session
5. Client requests new data so Adapter invokes WL.Server.InvokeHttp supplyng a cookie header with new cookie obtained in the last login step.
6. MFP sends and HTTP request with 2 cookies. First Cookie es the one supplied by the Adapt GICESSION=XXXXXXXX and another one that is added behind the scene by the MFP http client: GICSESSION=LOGGEDOFF. As backend receives this last cookie it returns a login form as a response

It seems that Worklight is not respecting the IGNORE_COOKIES setting.

I need a way to force WL.Server http client to clear/remove cookies once it receives a `Set-Cookie: GICSESSION = LOGGEDOFF` from backend.